# Symfony 3.4 - PropertyAccessor exception with ChoiceType

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This is really odd.  I'm getting the following exception:

> PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on,
>   but it found type "double" while trying to traverse path "Quantity" at
>   property "Quantity".

With the following code:

```
$choices = array();

$minimumSaleUnit = $cartItem->getProduct()->getMinimumSaleUnit();
$maxItems = $cartItem->getProduct()->getQuantity();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $value = $i * $minimumSaleUnit;

    if ($value <= $maxItems) {
        $choices["$value"] = $value;
    }
}

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($cartItem)
    ->add('quantity', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $choices, 'choice_label' => 'Quantity'])
    ->getForm();
```

`$choices` **is** an array of values:

[image]

So I'm not sure why the exception is happening.  It's not like I'm feeding it a straight double.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the the 'choice_label' definition to what the error is pointing to - i.e. there is no 'Quantity' property path in the choices array as the error says (see [doctrine choice_label](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label)). The intention is probably to use just `'label' => 'Quantity'`?

Comment: very nice catch!

Comment: Indeed, I stared at that part of my code and changed everything *except* that option.  ...oy, that'll teach me to code at 11 PM